# Why are switch cases so much slower than else if statements in Fish?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, fish

I wrote a `fish` function that returned each files/subdirectory of a directory with a corresponding icon.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/752253510795526175/783515933011869696/unknown.png

I had a `bash` function which does the exact same thing but written with elif statement.

```sh
lsi () {
  echo "   .. "
  if [[ "$1" != "" ]]; then
    echo "$1 here"
  fi
  ls $( echo $SHOW_HIDDEN | sed 's/true/-A/' | sed 's/false//') | while read entry; do
    if [ -d "(pwd)/$entry" ]; then
      echo "   $entry"
    elif [[ $entry =~ \.(sh|c)$ ]]; then
      echo "   $entry"
    elif [[ $entry =~ \.(md|txt|log)$|rc$ ]]; then
      echo "   $entry"
    elif [[ $entry =~ \.(jpg|png|svg|webp)$ ]]; then
      echo "   $entry"
    elif [[ $entry =~ \.fish$ ]]; then
      echo "   $entry"
    elif [[ $entry =~ \.py$ ]]; then
      echo "   $entry"
    elif [[ $entry =~ \.js$ ]]; then
      echo "   $entry"
    elif [[ $entry =~ \.mp4|mkv$ ]]; then
      echo "辶   $entry"
    elif [[ $entry =~ \.(mp3|m4a)$ ]]; then
      echo "   $entry"
    elif [[ $entry =~ \.(pdf)$ ]]; then
      echo "   $entry"
    elif [[ $entry =~ \.(tar|zip) ]]; then
      echo "遲    $entry"
    else
      echo "   $entry"
    fi
  done
}
```

When I did some testing in larger directories like `/usr/bin` or even `Pictures`, the `bash` script was noticeably faster especially on `/usr/bin`.

I rewrote the `fish` with else if statement

```
function lsi --description "ls with icons"
  echo "   .. "
  if $SHOW_HIDDEN
    set all -A
  end
  if ! test -z $argv[1]
    echo $argv[1]
  end
  for entry in (ls $all)
    if test -d "$entry"
      echo "   $entry"
    else if string match -rq '\.sh$' $entry
      echo "   $entry"
    else if string match -rq '\.(md|txt|log)|rc$' $entry
      echo "   $entry"
    else if string match -rq '\.(jpg|png|svg|webp|gif)$' $entry
      echo "   $entry"
    else if string match -rq '\.fish$' $entry
      echo "   $entry"
    else if string match -rq '\.rs$' $entry
      echo "   $entry"
    else if string match -rq '\.(c|h)$' $entry
      echo "   $entry"
    else if string match -rq '\.py$' $entry
      echo "   $entry"
    else if string match -rq '\.js$' $entry
      echo "   $entry"
    else if string match -rq '\.go$' $entry
      echo "   $entry"
    else if string match -rq '\.pdf$' $entry
      echo "   $entry"
    else if string match -rq '\.(mp4|mkv)$' $entry
      echo "辶   $entry"
    else if string match -rq '\.(tar|zip)$' $entry
      echo "遲    $entry"
    else
      echo "   $entry"
    end
  end
end
```

and now they perform almost identically.

I'd like to know why the `switch/case` version is so much slower. Is it because the `fish` built in is bad or does it has something to do the `switch/case` in general?

Answer (score 4):

You're not comparing the same thing - your fish code runs `sed` once per file, which needs to set up an entire process, which is slow.

`string` is a builtin, so it runs in the shell's process, which is fast, which is why your rewritten version is much faster.

Incidentally, fish's `case` can handle globs, so you can use something like

```
switch $entry
    case '*.fish'
       # do the fish thing
    case '*.'{jpg,png,svg,webp,gif}
       # do the thing for images
end
```

and remove the `sed`.

Comment: Thank you I didn't knew case and I suspect many other fish built ins could handled globs this way.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing the slower `switch` code is due to the sub-process call (`echo | sed`) being made for every file:

```
for entry in (ls $all)
  if ...
  else 
    switch (echo "$entry} | sed 's/.*\.//')    # sub-process call for each file processed!!
    ...
  end
end
```

Sure, you run a sub-process call (`echo|sed|sed`) in the `bash` solution, but that's a one-time call at the beginning of the `while` loop:

```
ls $( echo $SHOW_HIDDEN | sed 's/true/-A/' | sed 's/false//') | while read entry; do ...
```

The key issue here is the **number** of sub-process calls being made with the `fish/switch` code; with the `fish/switch` code you're going to notice long**er** run times for really large directories due to the increased **number** of sub-process calls.

I'm not familiar with `fish` but if it supports parameter expansion ...

```
$ entry='abc.def.pdf'
$ echo "${entry##*.}"       # show file extension
pdf
```

... you could probably replace the sub-process call to improve performance, eg:

```
switch "${entry##*.}"
```

Comment: It does not support parameter expansion, fish's string handling uses the `string` builtin. In this case the simplest solution is just to use glob-matching with `case`, however.